# ASMX service with heavy processing

Tags: c#, ajax, smtp, asmx

I have a website calling an ASMX service running on a server (Relatively old). I am struggling with an issue regarding an ajax request that requires some 10-20 seconds to fire the success method if not timed out.

Basically the user fills a set of info and customizes and image. When done, the user clicks a button which send the image base64 to the server and a huge json object with it. (Which is the information the user selected). Anyways, the service is responsible for doing the following:

- Create the image from the base64 string
- parse the Json object and organize it, then creates a 4 page pdf document with that image in it.
- Create an excel sheet of all requested information.
- Send an email to the user with the pdf attached
- Send an email to the company with all other attachments (pdf, excel and image)

It is a huge load, especially when using the SMTP object to send not one, but two emails.

Basically, Can we do this asynchronously without making the user wait for a "Success!!" message?

Thanks guys.

Comment: How about when the server receives the request, put it in a queue and immediately return a queue ID.  Then, the client can poll every few seconds to check if that queue ID is finished yet.

Comment: Well, when the server finishes, the user should be navigated back to the home page. So, if he needs to check it means he needs to wait, and wait for the same amount of time. I was thinking more of giving him the success and navigate away but the server still processes and all

Comment: I wouldn't say *Success* if the job hasn't finished yet.  I'd say something like "Your job is currently running..." and provide some sort of mechanism to go back and check the status later..  Perhaps your navigation bar can have status messages for running queue jobs.  Facebook does something similar with uploaded video; when it finishes processing, you're notified via a popup message.

Comment: DO you have any idea about this "Go back and check mechanism"? How can we do something like this when i send an ajax request, call the service exposed and get a return message your process is running? A repeated javascript function later on that sends another ajax request to check this queue ID or something? @MikeChristensen

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a standard queue task on the server, store call parameters and have a background task execute jobs from the queue.

When a job is as heavy as you describe, this would probably be a very good idea.

Let the task finish by posting a successful message to the clients mail address, or write to a user-specific web app log (readable from another web page).

You should implement with IIS recycling in mind.
Heavy server tasks can delay recycling if the task needs to finish before the recycling  kicks in. See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/ for more on that.

It requires more work, but the web server could call a self-hosted WCF service running as a windows service which in turn executes queued jobs.